When is Parker's first "I'm OK!" signal expected after it's close flyby of the Sun? Which dishes (if any) have been reserved for it?
The BBC's Dec 24, 2024 Spacecraft attempts closest-ever approach to Sun tells us

Parker Solar Probe launched in 2018, heading to the centre of our solar system.
It has already swept past the Sun 21 times, getting ever nearer, but the Christmas Eve visit is record-breaking.
At its closest approach, the probe is 3.8 million miles (6.2 million km) from our star's surface.
The probe will have to endure temperatures of 1,400C and radiation that could frazzle the onboard electronics.

and

In fact, it will be moving faster than any human-made object, hurtling at 430,000mph - the equivalent of flying from London to New York in less than 30 seconds.

But the interesting part to me is

Nasa scientists face an anxious wait over Christmas while the spacecraft is out of touch with Earth.
Nicola Fox says that as soon as a signal is beamed back home, the team will text her a green heart to let her know the probe is OK.

Since this close flyby of the solar surface is going to really push the limits of the spacecraft's thermal engineering (primarily because they chose not to go at night, those silly geese) there will no doubt be DSN(?) antennas reserved and lined up ready to pick up Parker's first "I'm OK!" message, or to respond with diagnostics or commands if something went awry that needs a quick recovery.
So I'm wondering:
Question: When is Parker's first "I'm OK!" signal expected after it's close flyby of the Sun? Which dishes (if any) have been reserved for it?
"Bonus points" for the minimum angular separation from the Sun that this first signal will be looked for.

The okay probe has arrived: The mission operations team at the Johns Hopkins Applied Physics Laboratory (APL) in Laurel, Maryland received the signal just before midnight EST, on the night of Dec. 26., see Nasa blog

@Heinrich the "mission operations team" may have been at APL, but I wonder if the dish used was their own, or they were linked to a DSN dish.

Canberra shows:

DSS34 SPP 27/12   1600-1820

Madrid's schedule page is broken, and Goldstone doesn't seem to have one.

I'm assuming 1600-1820 refers to UTC time?

@ToddWilcox I think so. What else could it be?

https://blogs.nasa.gov/parkersolarprobe/2024/12/20/parker-solar-probe-begins-record-setting-closest-approach-to-the-sun/

Parker is now on course to fly just 3.8 million miles (around 6.1 million kilometers) from the surface of the Sun on Tuesday, Dec. 24, at 6:53 a.m. EST. During closest approach, or perihelion, mission operations will be out of contact with the spacecraft, and Parker will transmit another beacon tone on Friday, Dec. 27, to confirm its health following the close flyby.


Which it just did: https://blogs.nasa.gov/parkersolarprobe/2024/12/27/nasas-parker-solar-probe-reports-successful-closest-approach-to-sun/

On a BBC youtube news clip we hear that a radio telescope outside Canberra Australia managed to capture the first ‘I’m OK’ signal. Not sure which one (it could certainly be DSN Canberra and the signal was linked directly to APL John Hopkins where it was night (and so the Sun would not be visible there).
After about 02:28 in the December 27, 2024 BBC YouTube video "Nasa makes history with closest-ever approach to Sun | BBC News":

BBC: Well we heard in that report from the Astronomer Royal of Scotland Professor Catherine Heymans. She's been telling me more about the news of that historic flyby
Heymans: It made its closest approach on Christmas Eve, but it was on the far side of the Sun, so it took until this morning for it to come back around for the Earth to be able to communicate with it. And at 5:00 a.m. this morning a radio station in Canberra Australia got the message that it was safe and sound which is an absolute joy for us as astronomers, because this this really is the finale of this mission.
It's been up for the last seven years, looping, doing an orbit between Venus and the Sun and each time it's gone past the sun it's got closer and closer and this is the first time it's reaching temperatures of about a thousand degrees Celcius, and amazingly it has survived!




